# Does IEnumerable.FirstOrDefaultAsync( predicate )?.ContinueWith() return if the result is null?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I am writing a section of code that is using the `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` `LINQ` method. I know that usually if you use it in an expression with the none async method that using a `?` afterwards returns without evaluating the rest of the method calls.

Ex. *Suedo code*

```
class Item = {
  string Name
  string Value
}

items = Item[]

var result = items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "Item One")?.Value;
```

If the `list` does not contain an `item` with the name "Item One", then result will be `null` and an `exception` won't be thrown because `null` doesn't have a property `Value`.

I am wanting to perform the same operation asynchronously, will this work:

```
list.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Name == "Item One")?
  .ContinueWith(result => result.Result.Value);
```

Will this just return without evaluating `ContinueWith()` if no such item is found? Or does the `?` not work in this way asynchronously?

Comment: `FirstOrDefaultAsync` will always return a `Task` (not `null`), that task will always have a continuation with `ContinueWith`, and it will crash gloriously with a `NullReferenceException` because you access `.Value` without a check. If you use `?.` in your continuation delegate there's no problem.

Comment: Rather than in between the methods, I'd use it in the predicate, e.g. `result => result.Result?.Value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown won't work, as it's checking if the `Task` returned by `FirstOrDefaultAsync` is null - which it will never be. Also, `ContinueWith` is overstretching, as its primary use is to chain asynchronous operations. Extracting a value isn't asynchronous, so why not just

```
var item = await list.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Name == "Item One");
var result = item?.Value;
```

You can one-line it if you wish

```
var result = (await list.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Name == "Item One"))?.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, that's perfect, I did think it would just give a task back so never null, just the answer I was looking for though!

Answer (score 1):

You must use parentheses () for asynchronous methods

```cs
var result =(await list.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Name == "Item One"))?.Value
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I would have marked yours correct as it is the same as below, except the answer below was slightly more detail, but thank you for the response!

Comment: My goal was to help you. Good luck